# Is it possible to use Attributes on Delphi method arguments?

Tags: delphi, attributes, rtti

Is this valid code with newer Delphi versions?

```
// handle HTTP request "example.com/products?ProductID=123"
procedure TMyRESTfulService.HandleRequest([QueryParam] ProductID: string);
```

In this example, the argument "ProductID" is attributed with `[QueryParam]`. If this is valid code in Delphi, there must also be a way to write RTTI based code to find the attributed argument type information.

See my previous question [Which language elements can be annotated using attributes language feature of Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119986/which-language-elements-can-be-annotated-using-attributes-language-feature-of-de?rq=1), which lists some language elements which have reported to work with attributes. Attributes on arguments were missing on this list.

Comment: Unfortunately the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Annotating_Types_and_Type_Members) is wrong. It says: *The following code blocks exemplify the different language constructs that allow annotations.* Having announced a complete enumeration of the language constructs, it then gives an incomplete list.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Rtti,
  SysUtils;

type
  QueryParamAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
  end;

  TMyRESTfulService = class
    procedure HandleRequest([QueryParam] ProductID: string);
  end;

procedure TMyRESTfulService.HandleRequest(ProductID: string);
begin

end;

var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  t: TRttiType;
  m: TRttiMethod;
  p: TRttiParameter;
  a: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  try
    t := ctx.GetType(TMyRESTfulService);
    m := t.GetMethod('HandleRequest');
    for p in m.GetParameters do
      for a in p.GetAttributes do
        Writeln('Attribute "', a.ClassName, '" found on parameter "', p.Name, '"');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: +1 - These attributes are powerful but not well documented :(